# Cassandra CQL: different SELECT results

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, nodetool

I am using latest Cassandra 2.1.0 and have the different results for the following queries.

```
select * from zzz.contact where user_id = 53528c87-0691-46f7-81a1-77173fd8390f 
                         and contact_id = 5ea82764-ce42-45f3-8724-e121c8b7d32e;
```

returns me one decired record but

```
select * from zzz.contact where user_id = 53528c87-0691-46f7-81a1-77173fd8390f;
```

returns 6 other rows except the row which is returned by first SELECT.

Structure of the keyspace/table is:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE zzz
WITH replication = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1' : '2' };

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contact (
    user_id uuid,
    contact_id uuid,
    approved boolean,
    ignored boolean,
    adding_initiator boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY ( user_id, contact_id )
);
```

Both instances are in keyspace and UN

```
d:\Tools\apache-cassandra-2.1.0\bin>nodetool status
Starting NodeTool
Note: Ownership information does not include topology; for complete information, specify a      keyspace
Datacenter: DC1
================
Status=Up/Down|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.0.146  135.83 KB  256     51.7%   6d035991-3471-498b-8051-55f99a2fdfed  RAC1
UN  192.168.0.216  3.26 MB    256     48.3%   d82f3a69-c6f8-4237-b50e-d2f370ac644a  RAC1
```

I have two Cassandra instances.

Tried command **"nodetool repair"** - didn't help.

Tried to add **ALLOW FILTERING** in the end of the queries - didn't help.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**UPD**:
here is result of queries:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

d:\Tools\apache-cassandra-2.1.0\bin>cqlsh 192.168.0.216
Connected to ClusterZzz at 192.168.0.216:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.0 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> select * from zzz.contact where user_id = 53528c87-0691-46f7-81a1-77173fd8390f and contact_id = 5ea82764-ce42-45f3-8724-e121c8b7d32e;

 user_id                              | contact_id                           | adding_initiator | approved | ignored
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------------+----------+---------
 53528c87-0691-46f7-81a1-77173fd8390f | 5ea82764-ce42-45f3-8724-e121c8b7d32e |            False |     True |   False

(1 rows)

cqlsh> select * from zzz.contact where user_id = 53528c87-0691-46f7-81a1-77173fd8390f;

 user_id                              | contact_id                           | adding_initiator | approved | ignored
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+------------------+----------+---------
 53528c87-0691-46f7-81a1-77173fd8390f | 6fc7f6e4-ac48-484e-9660-128476ca5bf9 |            False |    False |   False
 53528c87-0691-46f7-81a1-77173fd8390f | 7a240937-8b28-4424-9772-8c4c8e381432 |            False |    False |   False
 53528c87-0691-46f7-81a1-77173fd8390f | 8e6cb13a-96e7-45af-b9d8-40ea459df996 |            False |    False |   False
 53528c87-0691-46f7-81a1-77173fd8390f | 938af09a-0fe3-4cdd-b02e-cbdfb078335c |            False |     True |   False
 53528c87-0691-46f7-81a1-77173fd8390f | d84d9e7a-e81d-42a2-87b3-f163f7a9a646 |            False |     True |   False
 53528c87-0691-46f7-81a1-77173fd8390f | fd2ec705-1661-4cf8-98ef-46f627a9a382 |            False |    False |   False

(6 rows)

cqlsh>
```

**UPD #2:**
Worth to mention that my nodes are on Windows7 machines. On production, we use Linux, so there were no problems like I have it with Windows nodes.

Comment: Could you paste the ouput of each query?

Comment: This looks like a bug. You should file a JIRA with all the steps and setup you took.

Comment: I agree with @Richard -- just to be sure since you are using NetworkTopologyStrategy could you set your Consistency Level to each quorum? Type in cqlsh the command CONSISTENCY EACH_QUORUM; and then try again your query

Comment: Richard and @Carlo Bertuccini, first of all, thank you for your comments. Today, I was trying to change consistency level and retry those queries but Cassandra magically removed those "phantom" record. Now first query returns 0 results. However this was not an issue of some sync or so, because those issue was reproducible for few days before I posted this question here. I will let you know about consistency level change when I reproduce it again.

Comment: @walv if you do see the problem come back, you may also try running a `nodetool repair` on each node. Whenever you change the replication factor on a keyspace, this is required to propagate the data correctly. See Updating the replication factor here: [Creating and updating a keyspace](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/create_keyspace_c.html)

Comment: @BrianC, yes, I already tried it, please see the description. Also replication factor was not changed. Worth to mention that my nodes are on Windows7 machines. On production, we use Linux, so there were no problems like I have it with Windows nodes.

Comment: @CarloBertuccini, just reproduced it again and tried each_quorum: cqlsh> consistency each_quorum;
Consistency level set to EACH_QUORUM.
cqlsh> select * from zzz.contact where user_id = 938af09a-0fe3-4cdd-b02e-cbdfb078335c;
code=2200 [Invalid query] message="EACH_QUORUM ConsistencyLevel is only supported for writes"

Comment: Tried also all other consistency levels and nothing helped. I start hating C*.

Comment: Only restart of both C* nodes helped. Next attempt will be to try 'nodetool flush' if this issue occurs again.

Comment: @walv what exactly are the steps to reproduce this? Did you remove a node before this error occurs? Does "nodetool getendpoints ..." find the data on two nodes? how many nodes do you have in total?

Comment: I don't think consistency should affect reads as much as it affects writes (or their propagation to be more precise - "eventual consistency"). Would it be possible for you to paste a summary of cassandra.yaml configuration file (only the params changed from the template)